# javascript framework for plot maps

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to know if there is a good JS framework to convert an area map into a plottable one.

For example, if I have a map like this which identifies parkinglots with numbers, I want to identify the occupied lots with red color and vacant lots with other color.

[image: Parkinglot map]

What would be the best framework to achieve this. I saw D3.js but it has too much learning curve and we need to hard-code fixed points on an svg area. I'm looking for a quick alternative which could be a wrapper library of D3.js similar to what nvd3 is for charts

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at http://processingjs.org/ -- it is NOT a wrapper around D3, but it's designed to be easy to use.

(FWIW, I stopped using processing.js once I discovered D3 -- I like D3's flexibility despite the steeper learning curve.)

This post might be useful: https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/interactive-svg-map-with-processing-js.html